# TextView onclick method crashes the android application

Tags: android, kotlin

I have my TextView button in the login menu

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/webButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="Live Chat"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
```

and the `onClick` function in MainActivity that should connect me to a chatbot url on click

```
fun onClick(view: View?) {
        val browserIntent = Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("https://URL OF CHATBOT.html")
        )
        startActivity(browserIntent)
    }
```

When I try it with the button it works perfectly but when I switch to the TextView it crashes my app.

These are the messages I get after the crash

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example app_android, PID: 10611
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView with id 'webButton'
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:436)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:393)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: could you please share some logs?

Comment: oh sorry I thought I posted it. I will edit the post right away including the logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the onClickListener programmaticaly as you should always do:

```kotlin
webButton.setOnClickListener {
    val browserIntent = Intent(
        Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("https://URL OF CHATBOT.html")
    )
    startActivity(browserIntent)
}
```

You need to put this in the onCreate method of your activity

Comment: sorry I'm a bit confused. Where am I supposed to add this part?

Comment: should this part be added to the function onClick in my MainActivity? @McSlinPlay

Comment: OK I did that, should I do any changes in the xml of my button ?

Comment: remove the onclick thing

Answer (score 0):

You can set the click handler in xml with these attribute:

```
android:onClick="onClick"
android:clickable="true"
```

And don't forget the clickable attribute

Comment: also you should not add onClickListeners in xml. see my answer

Comment: @MKK I saw your logs now , change android:onClick="onClick" to android:onClick="TextClick" for example and try again

Comment: @anehme I did it but Im still getting a crash